# Access Title Property in ContentPage from XAML - Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

I've created a Xamarin.Forms project and then I've added a "Forms Xaml Page" called Main.xaml. After that I've tried to choose a Title to the ContentPage. But I cannot find the Title property in ContentPage. Visual Studio 2015 doesn't show this option to me (see picture bellow):

[Where's the Title property in ContentPage?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Micrg.png)

Also, I've put a StackLayout inside the ContentPage, but I cannot put a Button inside this StackLayout. I can put the Button inside the ContentPage, but not inside the StackLayout. Why that happens (see picture bellow)?

[Why is not possible to find a Button inside the StackLayout?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Br1wj.png)

I think I can access Title from codebehind, but not from XAML.

Comment: Intellisense is screwed up.  Try setting Title and running it, ignoring the Intellisense error.  It should build and run.

Comment: It runs. It worked. But I would like that my Visual Studio 2015 could help me in XAML. It is not good to make a xaml without the IDE help.

Comment: there are MANY other questions on SO that address fixing the Intellisense issue

Comment: I have some warnings: "The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll (v7.0) is greater than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project (v6.0). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project." and Also: "Warning IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project. Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me (answer from jonalza):

"Right click on XAML file -> click on "Open with..." option -> Select "XAML Desinger" in the list -> click on "Set as Default" button"
[enter link description here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/64005/intellisense-problem-in-visual-studio)

EDIT: As in your picture your line:  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>` appears in red and blue, and not only in blue, as usual, also check the answer from Brendan Zagaeski...

Comment: Also, I found the answer here: https://bsubramanyamraju.blogspot.com.br/2017/04/solution-xamarinforms-intellisense-is.html